# How do I send data from server to an app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, networking, communication

I want to send some data:
Database ==> server ==> app

I don't know what type of communication to use.
Restful api ? Tcp ? or just get request ?
App will get the data and display it in form of individual posts.

The server is in django with PostgreSQL, and the app is in react native,
There will be a couple posts a day(containing text and link to a image hosting on the server). The app doesn't need to store anything offline.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complex question, in the sense that it covers a great vastness of architecture. There are many approaches to implementing a solution. The question is very general, therefore we should understand in detail what the app does, what its functions are and the data it manages, the frequency of interaction with the database, if it needs changes and much more. However, on average, a solution that lends itself to these technologies is the development of a web server to manage RESTFUL calls. In such a way that services are exposed and the app can safely make calls (for example a CRUD) and manage data to your database. If you better enter some specifications we can analyze in detail a possible solution.